# MixStream player button is not displayed on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, flash

I have the bellow javascript on my html page. When I call this page from a windows pc/laptop or from a mac the flash player button displayed and the music I am streaming plays normally. When I call the same page from an android device or from an ios device the player button is not displayed also music doesn't heared.

```
<script>
        // MixStream Flash Player, http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/ 
        var flashvars = {}; flashvars.serverHost = "myserverhost"; flashvars.getStats = "1"; flashvars.autoStart = "1"; flashvars.textColour = ""; flashvars.buttonColour = ""; var params = {}; params.bgcolor = ""; params.wmode = "transparent";
</script>
```

Comment: Because Flash is not supported on those devices?

Comment: do you have any sugestion? I want to call this page from mobile devices

Comment: Look for alternatives that don't require Flash. E.g. http://jplayer.org/

Comment: can you sugest me an alternative?or a link about this alternative?

Comment: Um. I believe I did above. Here it is again: http://jplayer.org/

Comment: sorry i didn show this... I will check it and repost

Comment: I found this demo http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-07/ but how can i apply it?

Comment: Well do your research, see code samples